# Installing Trac as a Windows Service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, trac

As the title suggests, I'm trying to install Trac as a Windows Service on Windows Server 2008. I've looked into the instructions at [Installing Trac as a Windows Service](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#InstallingasaWindowsService). Out of the different options given there, I would prefer an `Option 1` like approach which uses some Windows utilities instead of installing additional software but the instructions seem a bit outdated for Windows Server 2008 as `instsrv.exe` and `srvany.exe` are not available for Server 2008. There is a suggestion to use `winserv.exe` but I can't find it anywhere and the suggested Google search does not provide any credible results.

Is there a way to use the `sc` Windows utility to install Trac as a service? Has anyone tried this?

> Update: I tried using `sc` but that does not work. `sc` only interacts with programs developed as Windows Service Applications so they have hooks to interact with `sc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you restricted to using `tracd` to host your Trac installation?  If you use a real web server, this is typically a bit easier.  Web servers like IIS and Apache typically install themselves as a service.  If you set up something other than `tracd` to serve up your Trac site, it will most likely run as a service by default.  In general, you'll have a better experience using a full-featured web server like Apache instead of the minimalistic `tracd`.

Comment: Currently, the current setup is using `tracd`. If there is a solution using just `tracd` I would prefer that. I can look into the using a web server later.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem using *winserv.exe*, that can be downloaded from this tutorial page: http://wiki.go-redrock.com/wiki/TechAsService

Once you get the binary file run:

```
"C:\path\to\winserv.exe" install tracd -displayname "tracd" -start auto "C:\path\to\python.exe" c:\path\to\python\scripts\tracd-script.py <your tracd parameters>

net start tracd
```

Hope you can solve your problem like I did!

Comment: By Far the easiest way to install tracd as win service.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to easily install Trac on a Windows server, I can recommend [Bitnami Trac Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/trac) to you. It comes as 2 services, one for Apache web server running Trac as python module and one for SVN.